# Deleting a document from Cosmos DB - entity with the specified id does not exist in the system

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb

I'm experiencing an issue when trying to delete a document from `CosmosDb`, from my understanding I first have to load the document I want to delete and then pass in the `document.SelfLink` into the following method:

```
DeleteDocumentAsync
```

However, when I try to delete it throws the following error:

*entity with the specified id does not exist in the system*

I know the document exists as I'm able to see the document within the `document` variable.

Below is my current code setup:

```
 private static void DeleteDocument()
    {
        var feedOptions = new FeedOptions
        {
            MaxItemCount = -1,
            EnableCrossPartitionQuery = true
        };

        var document = _documentClient
            .CreateDocumentQuery(UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(_databaseName, _collection), feedOptions)
            .Where(x => x.Id == "ba00d500-de61-411e-b8ef-f749b23cc326")
            .AsEnumerable()
            .SingleOrDefault();

        if (document == null) return; // Document is not null when I check here

        _documentClient.DeleteDocumentAsync(UriFactory.CreateDocumentUri(_databaseName, _collection, document.Id), new RequestOptions { PartitionKey = new Microsoft.Azure.Documents.PartitionKey(document.Id) })
            .GetAwaiter()
            .GetResult();
    }
```

Here is the document in CosmosDb:

[image]

I've also tried referring to the `document.SelfLink` instead of using the `UriFactory.CreateDocumentUrl` yet the outcome is still the same.

Update.

Seems passing in `Undefined.Value` as the `PartitionKey` seems to work:

```
_documentClient.DeleteDocumentAsync(document.SelfLink, new RequestOptions { PartitionKey = new Microsoft.Azure.Documents.PartitionKey(Undefined.Value) })
            .GetAwaiter()
            .GetResult();
```

Which I find really odd personally.

Comment: The document has `id` (lower case)  but your Linq predicate has `Id` (and you are referencing `document.Id`)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything weird, just a need to know the partition key and specify it when sending a request to server. **Partition key is part of document identity just as `id`-field**. Even if the partition key is `undefined`.

When you queried documents, you explicitly requested a scan through all partitions via  `EnableCrossPartitionQuery = true` which allowed you to omit partition key from query and still get results. You should have passed in PArtition key there too, to save costs, but it works.

For delete, there is no cross-partition deletes and you have to pass in the partition key. Once you did, the document was found, and could be deleted. Quite expected.

In addition, **NO you don't have to load a document to delete it**, that's jsut extra complexity, cost and roundtripto server. All you need to know is the identity of document to be deleted (database + collection + partition + id). For cosmosDB V2 client, a la this example:

```
var documentUri = UriFactory.CreateDocumentUri(databaseName, containerName, documentId);
var options = new RequestOptions() { PartitionKey = new PartitionKey(partition) };

await cosmosClient.DeleteDocumentAsync(documentUri, options).ConfigureAwait(false);
```